# I'm getting a 502 for every second call of this Lambda - AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have the following Lambda function, that I invoke via the API gateway:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '[my_endpoint]',
    user: '[my_user]',
    password: '[my_password]',
    database: '[my_db]',
});

// console.log(connection);
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    connection.query('SELECT [field_name] FROM [table_name] WHERE [field_name] = \"' + event['queryStringParameters']['myParam'] + '\"', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            connection.end();
            throw error;
        } else {
            // connected!
            console.log("Success! : " + event['queryStringParameters']['myparam'])
            console.log(results);

            var response = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "my_header": "success"
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(results),
                "isBase64Encoded": false

            };

            callback(error, response);
            connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, response);});
        }
    });
};
```

For some reason, I get status codes 200 and 502 for every second GET method call (I.e. a 200 status code with data on one call, and then a 502 status code on the next call, changing every other call)

Looking at CloudWatch, I see the following error:

```
 Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit
```

Any insight into why this is happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You probably have a problem here ```callback(error, response);
            connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, response);});``` You are calling the callback that gets into the lambda handler and then calling connection end. You should restructure your code to handle the connection as needed and then finally call the callback.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda supports Node.js [v.8.10](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/), so you can write your code using `async/await` and `Promises`.

```
// You don't need callback here with nodejs v.8.10
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host: '[my_endpoint]',
       user: '[my_user]',
       password: '[my_password]',
       database: '[my_db]',
  });

  const queryRow = `SELECT ${field_name} FROM ${table_name} WHERE ${field_name} = "${event['queryStringParameters']['myParam']}"`;

  // We use only resolve for simplicity. In this particular case to remove try/catch. 
  // In your production code you should use resolve and reject to handle promise.
  const queryResult = await new Promise((resolve) => {
     connection.query(queryRow, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) return resolve(false);
        resolve(results);
      });
  });

  // We can close connection here, because no more actions with db required.
  connection.end();

  if (!queryResult) {
    return { statusCode: 404, body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'DB error' }) };
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(queryResult),
    headers: {
      my_header: 'success',
    },
  };

};
```

About [`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=770786).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code! I tried to implement this, but still get this error every other run of the lambda: Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.

Comment: @CornelVerster try to create `connection` inside lambda function

Comment: I am facing a similar issue of "Error: Quit inactivity timeout", I'm using mysql package version "mysql": "^2.17.1"